# if $\alpha $ is transcendental , there is no way to write $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ as a polynomial in $\alpha$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

We had the proposition :

If $\alpha$ is algebraic $\mathbb{Q[\alpha]}=\mathbb{Q(\alpha)}$ .

Let  $\alpha$ be transcendental .

Suppose $$ \frac{1}{\alpha}=a_n\alpha^n+a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}+...+a_0$$
Then I can multiply everything by $\alpha$ . I do not know how to continue .

I think the right side has to be zero leading to a contradiction .

Thanks for help .

Comment: Anabolic should say that $a_n,\dots , a_0$ are rational numbers, but he did not, so it is a bad question.

Comment: The proposition holds only for algebraic integers . Now I have to show that I cannot write $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ as a polynomial in $\alpha$ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $n = 0$, i.e. $\frac{1}{\alpha}=a_{0}$, then $\alpha = \frac{1}{a_{0}}\in \mathbb{Q}$, a contradiction. So $n > 0$, and if you multiply $\alpha$ it gives
$$
a_{n}\alpha^{n+1} + \cdots + a_{1}\alpha^{2} + a_{0} \alpha -1 = 0,
$$
so that $\alpha$ is algebraic.